# How to add API version in path by convention in dotnet 6 ex: (/api/v1/blog)

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I was searching for a way to add api version in the path without adding a path parameter like this:
[image: swagger capture for a path parameter to add api version]

the solution was to create a class that implements `IApplicationModelConvention`
like this:

```
public class DefaultRouteConvention : IApplicationModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
    {
        foreach (var applicationController in application.Controllers)
        {
            var apiVersionAttribute = applicationController.Attributes.OfType<ApiVersionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (apiVersionAttribute == null) continue;
            var apiVersion = apiVersionAttribute.Versions.FirstOrDefault();
            if (apiVersion != null)
            {
                applicationController.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {

                        Template = $"api/v{apiVersion.MajorVersion}/[controller]"
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can simply add it to startup

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new DefaultRouteConvention());
});
```

finally, you need to add the Api version attribute to each controller:

```
[ApiVersion(1.0)]
[ApiController]
public class ResourceController : ControllerBase
{}
```

if you don't want to add the attribute to each controller simply add this in startup:

```
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
});
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

you need to add `Asp.Versioning.Mvc` from nuget.

Comment: Would, you kindly confirm, are you looking for the solution or just sharing your steps, the way you have resolved it?